# jQuery Out of Bounds Error in Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Why does this code throw and out-of-bounds error, it seems like it should work fine.

```
var a = [[[3,4],[0,0],[0,6],[7,8],[0,9],[8,3]]];
    var b = [3,4];
    console.log(jQuery.inArray(b,a[0][0]));
```

Comment: maybe because `'b'` string doesn't exist in the `a[0][0]` array (is [3,4])? =)

Answer (score 3):

You can't find it, because it's not there. In JavaScript, just because two arrays have similar contents doesn't mean that the arrays themselves are equal. Try the following in your console:

```
[3,4] === [3,4];
```

The output will be that of `false`, since two similar arrays are not the *same* array. If you wanted this code to work, you'd have to actually put one array into another, like this:

```
var a = [3,4];
var b = [5,a]; // [5,[3,4]]

jQuery.inArray(a, b); // a is found at index 1
```

If you merely want to check for the presence of a *similar* array within the haystack, you could stringify the entire needle and haystack, and look for the substring:

```
var needle = JSON.stringify([3,4]);
var haystack = JSON.stringify([[3,4],[5,6]]);

haystack.indexOf(needle); // needle string found at index 1
```

You should note however that the index returned is the index the *stringified* representation is found at, and not the actual index the array is found at within the haystack. If you wanted to find the true index of the array, we'd have to modify this logic just a bit:

```
var needle = JSON.stringify([3,4]),
    haystack = [[3,4],[5,6]],
    position = -1,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
    if (needle === JSON.stringify(haystack[i])) {
        position = i;
    }
}

console.log(position); // needle found at index 0​​​
```

Run this code: http://jsfiddle.net/DTf5Y/

Comment: But I need to find array a in array b, what would be another way to do it?

Comment: But a array values can be any arrays, so I need found direct this array [3,4]

Comment: @user1833872 I understand. Stringify both arrays, and look up one in the result of the other.

Comment: `var a = [[3,4],[0,0],[0,6],[7,8],[0,9],[8,3]];
        var b = [3,4];
        var a_string = JSON.stringify(a); 
        var b_string = JSON.stringify(b);
        console.log(b_string.indexOf( a_string ));` returns -1

Comment: You should be trying to find b within a in that example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have too many square braces.

```
var a = [[[3,4],[0,0],[0,6],[7,8],[0,9],[8,3]]];
    var b = [3,4];
    console.log(jQuery.inArray('b',a[0][0]));
```

should be

```
var a = [[3,4],[0,0],[0,6],[7,8],[0,9],[8,3]];
    var b = [3,4];
    console.log(jQuery.inArray('b',a[0][0]));
```